# What is the derivative of $X^{T}A^{-1}X$ with respect to $X$ if the matrix $A$ also depends on $X$.

Tags: matrices, derivatives

> $A$ is $N\times N$ symmetric matrix. $X$ is $N\times 1$ vector.

---

What I got is the following

$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial X}} = {X{^T}}{A^{ - 1}} - {X^T}{A^{ - 1}}\frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial X}}{A^{ - 1}}X + {X^T}{A^{ - 1}}$

Comment: What kind of object is $\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}$? BTW, it is more common to write vectors as lower-case letters.

Comment: How exactly did you get that equation you wrote?

Comment: The last summand should be $X^TA^{-T}$ instead of $X^TA^{-1}$.

Comment: I think I did some mistake I think the above formula is incorrect since as you stated. I'm trying to see if I can get a close formula for this.

Comment: I get $f'(X) = X^TA^{-1} - X^TA^{-1}(\frac{\partial A}{\partial X_k}A^{-1}X)_{k=1}^n + X^TA^{-T}$. Here, I use the notation $(Y_k)_{k=1}^n = (Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$.

Comment: That is exactly what I got after I worked it again. I think I should have been more clear about the notation. thank you so much for your help and insight.